# Circular dependency between the following tasks: :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets \--- :app:recordFilesBeforeBundleCommandRelease

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

After I add plugin code Push, i have this error ( https://scans.gradle.com/s/u65liapjhvcyo/console-log )

STACK TRACE AND/OR SCREENSHOTS

https://scans.gradle.com/s/u65liapjhvcyo/console-log
Environment

```
react-native-code-push version: 5.4
react-native version: 0.55.4
Gradle Version : 3.1.3
```

Please how to do to pass ?

Thanks

Comment: i add org.gradle.configureondemand=true in file gradle.properties , I resolve my problem. I do not know how to create another problem or not, but if a person has a better proposal I am interested.
Thank you

Comment: Environment:
  OS: Windows 10
  Node: 8.11.1
  Yarn: 1.6.0
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: Not Found
  Xcode: N/A
  Android Studio: Version  3.0.0.0 AI-171.4443003

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4

Comment: this solution add org.gradle.configureondemand=true is file gradle.properties , impossible your run command react-natibe run-android ,  the server window closes after the build , impossible to work in mode  development

Comment: i resolve this problem : 
 remove line runBefore("bundle${targetName}JsAndAssets", recordFilesBeforeBundleCommand) in file codePush.gradle